# ¿Cómo ordenar fechas por mes y día excluyendo el año en Android?

Tags: java, android, date

Tengo una lista con objeto personalizado `MyContact` el campo  `eventDate` es formato `Date` donde se guarda la fecha de nacimiento del contacto.

```
public class MyContact {
   private String id;
   private String displayName;
   private Date eventDate;

   ..getters...setters...
}
List<MyContact> mList = new ArrayList<>(getAniversariosContactos(this));
```

El orden que obtengo ahora mismo:

```
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Sat Jan 27 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Sat Feb 02 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 1985
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Wed Nov 06 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 1991
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Mon Mar 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 1995
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Sat May 15 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 1999
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Mon Jan 24 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2000
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Thu Sep 28 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017
D/ContactsHelper: fecha: Fri Sep 29 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017
```

Me gustaría ordenar la lista por mes y día sin tener en cuenta el año.

En resumen es para listar los aniversarios futuros.
La fecha pivote sea la actual o bien se puede especificar cualquiera así se podrá de paso obtener los aniversarios concluidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar un `Comparator<MyContact>` donde compares los objetos de acuerdo al algoritmo deseado.

Ejemplo (basado en Java 7):

```
Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<MyContact>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyContact contacto1, MyContact contacto2) {
        Calendar eventDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar eventDate2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        eventDate1.setTime(contacto1.getEventDate());
        eventDate2.setTime(contacto2.getEventDate());

        int month1 = eventDate1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int month2 = eventDate2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        if (month1 != month2) return Integer.compare(month1, month2);
        int day1 = eventDate1.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int day2 = eventDate2.get(Calendar.DATE);
        return Integer.compare(day1, day2);
    }
});
```

Si usas Java 6, puedes cambiar `Integer.compare` por la implementación que lleva en Java 7: `(x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1)`. Sugiero colocar esto en un método estático, así:

```
public static int comparar(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Así, estas líneas:

```
if (month1 != month2) return Integer.compare(month1, month2);
/* ... */
return Integer.compare(day1, day2)
```

Serían:

```
if (month1 != month2) return comparar(month1, month2);
/* ... */
return comparar(day1, day2);
```

Comment: Tienes alguna alternativa sin usar Intenger.compare, ya que me marca que es compatible de >= KitKat ?